# Connect points in array with \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, loops

How can I get the next element in array that's being looped with `\foreach`?

Here is an example what I'd like to achieve, but it obviously doesn't work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\points{(0.31,-0.23), (1,0.68), (0.54,1.35), (2,2)}

\foreach \p [count=\i] in \points{
    \draw \points[\i] -- \points[\i+1];
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that it's vital for me to use this kind of approach, because I want my code to be flexible, so that I could remove or add as many points in `\points` array as I want, so `\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- ...` isn't suitable for me. And the actual task is a bit more complicated than a simple points connection, but it's based on the solution of this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to type `\draw (0.31,-0.23)--(1,0.68)--(0.54,1.35)--(2,2);`?

Comment: @egreg check the remark under MWE. There will be more complicated relation that requires getting neighbor elements in the array `\points`.

Comment: So show where the complications arise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I guess I found the most suitable solution for me, that's why I mark this answer as 'accepted'. However, please consider other answers as well, because they might be more appropriate for your needs.

Here are two similar approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\points{{{0.31,-0.23}, {1,0.68}, {0.54,1.35}, {2,2}}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{dim(\points)-2}

\foreach \i [evaluate={\ax=\points[\i][0]; \ay=\points[\i][1]; \bx=\points[\i+1][0]; \by=\points[\i+1][1]}]
          in {0,...,\len}{
    \draw (\ax,\ay) -- (\bx,\by);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

­

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\points{{{0.31,-0.23}, {1,0.68}, {0.54,1.35}, {2,2}}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{dim(\points)-2}

\foreach \i in {0,...,\len}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ax}{\points[\i][0]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ay}{\points[\i][1]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bx}{\points[\i+1][0]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\by}{\points[\i+1][1]}
    \draw (\ax,\ay) -- (\bx,\by);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

­

I think it worth referencing these posts that came in useful while looking for the solution:

[Iteratively draw and connect nodes via `\foreach`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/385793/213149)

[Draw a path between many nodes using foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75146/213149)

[Given an array of 2D points, how to access individual elements in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594635/213149)

[2D tikz matrices: iteration and addressing elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404135/213149)

[array of coordinates and array of strings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532717/213149)

[TikZ \foreach loop evaluate variable using pgfmath function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101843/213149#comment221420_101847)

[\foreach has a problem with ‘initially’ argument in remember part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79586/213149)

[pgfmathparse in foreach, use result as node coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357658/213149)

[tikz foreach index in variable name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38514/213149)

And also an example in subsection [94.2 Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Operators](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=1033) at p. 1033
[image]

Comment: Very detailed answer, good!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `remember` to access the previous point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\points{(0.31,-0.23), (1,0.68), (0.54,1.35), (2,2)}

\foreach \p [count=\i,remember=\p as \lastp] in \points{
    \ifnum\i>1\relax
    \draw \lastp -- \p;
    \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's already something. May I wonder if it's possible to access `\i+2`, the last one or any other element in the array?

Comment: @antshar I think that this kind of array confuses pgf. The `\foreach` loop has a special switch for lists of coordinates, but pgf list operations seem to get confused by them. This means that you can in principle access elements of the list but would have to make some extra effort to undo the conversion pgf does to it. BTW, the above plot can also be produced with `\draw plot coordinates {<list>};`, where however the list should not contain commas between the coordinates, so it should rather be `{(0.31,-0.23) (1,0.68) (0.54,1.35) (2,2)}` in this case.

Comment: `pgffor` has special handling of pairs. `pgfmanual`, Sec. 88 "Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement" reads, "since pairs are such a natural and
useful case, they get a special treatment by the `\foreach` statement. When a list item starts with a `(` everything up to the next `)` is made part of the item.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thanks for the heads up! Yes, I am actually using this fact in the loop. However, I think that the question asking about the extraction of one (pair of) coordinate(s) from a list, and I was not able to convince the `array` function of pgf to do that (unless doing complicated stuff). Of course, one could use `\foreach` for that ...

Comment: Ya, `pgfmath`'s `array` function takes more strict syntax.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ do you know if it's possible to make such a parsing of coordinate pairs outside of `\foreach`. So that if I have the same `\def\points{(0.31,-0.23), (1,0.68), (0.54,1.35), (2,2)}`, how can I make a pgf array of it that can be iterated. For now I have to use multiple curly braces for the list (see my answer).

Comment: @antshar You could loop through `\points` and construct a new macro: `\usepackage{etoolbox} \def\pointsBraced{} \foreach \p in \points { \xappto{\pointsBraced}{{\p},}}`.

Answer (score 3):

If for you it is not a problem to separate your points in the list with a char different from `,` (I used `;`), because the comma is already used to separate the coordinates, it is very easy with `listofitems` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{;}

\begin{document}

\readlist\points{(0.31,-0.23); (1,0.68); (0.54,1.35); (2,2)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {2,...,\pointslen}
        {\draw \points[\i-1] -- \points[\i];}
\end{tikzpicture}

With more points:

\readlist\points{(0.31,-0.23); (1,0.68); (0.54,1.35); (2,2); (3,4); (4,5)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i  in {2,...,\pointslen}
        {\draw \points[\i-1] -- \points[\i];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `pgffor` can handle comma-separated list of pairs like `(0,0), (1,1), ...`, see [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621554/connect-points-in-array-with-foreach#comment1551758_621560) under @ABC's answer.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ You should add your own answer

Comment: It's off-topic to the current question, only minor corrections/improvements to the existing answer, so I think comment(s) is appropriate.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ As you like, but I don't think it's off-topic, it's exactly what the OP want

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's a neat solution as well.

Comment: @antshar You're welcome!